# How do I clone a repository so it can be imported normally in Python?

Tags: python, git, anaconda

I am looking for a way (or a folder) to clone a Git repository so after doing so, I can import it in Python like I import any other library.

Command line:

```
git clone newpackage.git
```

Python:

```
import newpackage
```

Maybe any Python related folder in my system/user variables?

Comment: Does this help? https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support

Comment: Either `git clone` + `pip install` or `pip install git+…` directly from a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the repository is not enough, you also have to actually install it.

Usually;

```
cd newpackage
python setup.py install
```

(You will probably need root/administrator provileges to install a package.)

After installation, you should be able to import the package.